# Optimal way to compare a string with a set of values and return a value

Tags: java

I have written a method. I want to return the employee type based on class.

I am thinking if there is any better and standard implementation here.

```
public static EmployeeType decideEmployeeType(String className)
    {
        if(className.equalsIgnoreCase("A") || className.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
        {
            return EmployeeType.ADMIN;
        }            
        else if(className.equalsIgnoreCase("S") || className.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
        {
            return EmployeeType.SERVICE;   
        }
        else
        {
            //throw exception
        }
    }
```

Can some one suggest, better approach.

Comment: what you could do is:
String check1 = "aA1";
if ( check1.contains(testString))
  return EmployeeType.ADMIN;

I do hope the above code is meant as example, and is not your actual code, since it 'll never compile. also, equalsIgnoreCase on a digit is pointless.

Comment: class is a keyword in Java, you cannot use it as a variable name like you are using it as a parameter of type String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can give a code example which is easily extendible by changing a constant without hampering the business logic:

```
private static HashMap<String, EmployeeType> employeeTypeTranslations = new HashMap<String,EmployeeType> () {{
  put("a",EmployeeType.ADMIN);
  put("s",EmployeeType.SERVICE);
  put("1",EmployeeType.ADMIN);
  put("2",EmployeeType.SERVICE);

}};

public static EmployeeType decideEmployeeType(String class) {
        employeeTypeTranslations.get(class.toLowerCase());
    }
```

What this allows is that you can in future may be externalize this map to a properties file or an XML or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDK 7 you can use switch with strings.

```
switch(className){
        case "A": /* do your stuff */
         break;
        default:
         //do default stuff
}
```

Im not sure why you having class 1 OR A (i guess it's because of ProGuard or any other obfuscator?

If yes, use a Constant. Class a = YourClass.getClass();

The Obfuscator will change it automatically.

Comment: -1 switch cannot be used to compare String values. However can be used for chars but the question is regarding String values.

Comment: java 7 can use string inn switch

Comment: Im not sure what you are talking about, but it is possible to use strings. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: @GPS **Wrong.** It can be used with strings. However the given example won't compile.

Comment: 'a' is a char not a String. It should be "a"

Comment: Okay ! Got it.. Removed my -1

Comment: Updated. Now it should compile just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way, but you can use 'valueOf' if you are using enum.

```
EmployeeType.valueOf("ADMIN") // return EmployeeType.ADMIN
```

NOTE: case sensitive